# datatype of a method returning a list of Accounts

Tags: unit-test

For a method in apex we are creating accounts and rather than inserting we are directly returning the list out of that method in apex?

My code:

```
public XXXXX createAccount(some arguments){
    List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();
    //some code
    accList.add(accts);
    return accList;
}
```

What should be the datatype here ?
I tried sObjects that doesn't works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning `accList` which (I assume) is of type `List<Account>` so that is that the datatype should be using. See example below.

```
public List<Account> createAccount(some arguments){
    List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();
    //some code
    accList.add(accts);
    return accList;
}
```

Comment: thanks !!!....just can we return acclist and contList(Contact related to account) in the same method using <sObjects>......a code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: @codeath If you query the Contacts in the same SOQL as the Accounts, then each Account object returned will have a relationship field populated (called Contacts) that is a list of the related Contact objects. So the signature posted above will work unchanged to do what you want; probably best though to change the method name to something like "queryAccountsAndRelatedContacts" to try and make what is going on clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `List<Account>`, as `accList` is a list of  `List<Account>` . So method should be like below -

```
public List<Account> createAccount(some arguments){
    List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();
    accList.add(accts);
    return accList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original question has been answered, you need to return `List<Account>`.

As for how to return Accounts with Contacts, you could use a multi dimensional map, like so:

```
public Map<Id, Map<Account, List<Contact>>> createAccount(some arguments){

    Map<Id, Map<Account, List<Contact>>> = accountContactsMap = new Map<Id, Map<Account, List<Contact>>>();

    // Query for accounts & contacts
    for (Account acc : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account]) {

        accountContactsMap.put(acc.Id, new Map<Account, List<Contact>>);
        accountContactsMap.get(acc.Id).put(acc, acc.Contacts);

    }

    return accountContactsMap
}
```